# Run command on iOS-Device over USB

Tags: c#, ios

I'm trying to run a simple command on my iOS-Device over USB, **not over SSH**.
The device is jailbroken as well.
The iTunesMobileDevice.dll file has a function called `sendCommandToDevice()`,
it's private so I unfortunately can't access it through DllImport.
By the way, I am using MobileDevice to establish an USB-connection.

To be more precise:
I want to code a C# application that runs a command on the connected iDevice once the user clicks a button (e.g. `killall Safari`).

Does anyone know how this might work?

sendCommandToDevice-Code doesn't work:

```
[DllImport("iTunesMobileDevice.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern unsafe int sendCommandToDevice(void* conn, void* command);

public unsafe void sendCommandToDevice(string Command)
{
    MobileDevice.sendCommandToDevice(this.iPhoneHandle, MobileDevice.__CFStringMakeConstantString(MobileDevice.StringToCFString(Command)));
}
```

Throws

> "System.EntryPointNotFoundException" The procedure entry point
>   sendCommandToDevice could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   iTunesMobileDevice.dll